# How to send RTPPackets after SIP call Invite request method?

Tags: java, android, sip, voip, rtp

I am developing an application based on **VOIP(SIP)**. I am able to send Invite and Invite-Ack between two emulators but now i would like to send **RTPpacket** after Invite-ack message in **SIP** call flow.

Is it possible to send like that. If yes, please can anyone help me regarding this.

After that i m going to integrate this for both send and receive part of **SIP** video call.

Any help would be appreciated lot!!! Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think i will have to look at the RTP implementation of sipdroid or csipsimple, that might help me..

Comment: yeah see this,it might be help to you [RtpStreamSender.java](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/media/RtpStreamSender.java) and [RtpStreamReceiver.java](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/media/RtpStreamReceiver.java)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes, the protocol supports this. How exactly to do it depends on the particular SIP stack you are using. The default Android one is fairly high level and does not have this option.

Comment: I don't know this particular stack, refer to its documentation. Search for 'early media'.